# How to add a static library to a project that uses cocoapods (iOS)

Tags: ios, static-libraries, cocoapods

I have a project that uses cocoapods for some time. Recently, I bought an external library from a vendor. This library was sent to me as a static library (.a) and two headers files (.h).

I imported both files and added the static libraries Build Phases -> Link Binary With Librareis. However, my project can not find the static library.

The same library works fine on a project that does not use cocoapods (and workspace). So I think this is a compatibility problem with the configuration made by cocoapods. I've tried to add the static library path to Header Search Path and Library Search Path. No success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add the static library with the correct path and is it readable?

Comment: Yea! It's at the correct path and it's readable.

Comment: by the way, what is the error that arises during the build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard procedure of adding library is

1. add to `OTHER LINKER FLAGS`  `-l${name_of_library_without_LIB_prefix_and_.a_suffix}`, for example `libz.a` will look like `-lz`
2. add your library  to the library search path. There are useful global vars

> $(PROJECT_DIR)
>
> $(SRCROOT)

You can reference it while defining path to your library

3. add to the HEADER SEARCH PATH path to library headers. You can also use $(PROJECT_DIR) and $(SRCROOT) as a part of the path.

As for using external libraries with `CocoaPods` - there should be no difference apart from having `$(inherited)` as a first line of all this settings - library search path, header search path and other linker flags.